# WPF - set text to Window as TextBox

Tags: wpf

i would like catch text in WPF Window. For example, application window will focus and I am going to write without focus in some textbox. My application has input from barcode reader. I want users to be able read a barcode without click to some textbox - for faster work. It is possible? I tried event PreviewKeyDown but application catch only first char. My barcodes are in format #12000012546 and barcode reader emulate numeric keyboard (Shift + num) - for example instead of char # KeyEventArgs return only "System". This is my code:

```
   static string text = string.Empty;
   private void MainWindow_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
      text += e.Key.ToString();
      if (text.Length == 12)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(text)
         text = null;
       }
     }
```

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Barcode reader is really doing key presses (`Shift + number`) to do your `#` character, then check this out. This was tested on an Spanish Keyboard, so the `#` character is on my `3` key (`Key.D3`)

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex("(#)|([0-9])");
    var keystr = e.Key.ToString();

    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
    {
        if (regex.Match(keystr).Success)
            if (e.Key == Key.D3) textBox1.Text += "#";
    }
    else if (regex.Match(keystr).Success)
        textBox1.Text += keystr.Replace("D","");
}
```